# Portal 2 coop says my Ping Tool is Not Assigned

Tags: portal-2, keyboard

At the start of Portal 2 coop, GLaDOS wants me to use my ping tool to select my favorite animal, but the help text says the button is Not Assigned.  I tried to edit my keyboard controls, but I can't find the Ping Tool in the Edit Keys dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Edit Keys dialog, the Ping Tool is called the "Communications Menu" instead.  Assign a key to that (the default is <kbd>F</kbd>), and then you'll be able to ping an animal by placing the crosshair on it and pressing that key.